# Sieve algorithm that only pick every integer once?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have developed an algorithm, Sieves like, that only pick every integer once. The Sieve algorithm of course selecting integers in as many iterations as the integer has distinct prime factors.

Is this seen before (I haven't found it) ?

Comment: Sorry, but this is incomprehensible. 

Comment: Have you compared with Pritchard's wheel sieve? http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=685983

Comment: Thank you François,

That was what I meant, and I will look at Pritchard's wheel to compare.  Sorry if my question was difficult to comprehend.

Jorgen


Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may interest you that the asymptotically fastest prime sieve (of Atkin-Bernstein) spends less than unit time on each number in the interval, by considering increasingly thin congruence classes as its input increases.  (Of course it spends positive time, $O(\log n/\log\log n)$, on each *prime*.)

Comment: Thanks Charles!
However I'm looking for beauty - not speed :-)
Jorgen


Comment: It may be related to the classical sieve of Sundaram, q.v.